# Migrate from Android Kotlin crypto chiper to Flutter Dart

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart, 3des

I am trying to replace decrypt code from Android platform to Flutter using Dart
and having trouble with 3D(DESede) decrypt algorithm,

Kotlin code: (Android crypto)

```
   val data2 = Base64.decode("9KOnBwiSR/SY60q55ashNg==", Base64.NO_WRAP)
        val myKey = SecretKeySpec("aRVFPuBfEPZH6k01".toByteArray(), "DESede")

        val c3des = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding")
        c3des.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myKey)
        val cipherText = c3des.doFinal(data2)

        return String(cipherText)
```

Tried this one without succeed(Flutter Dart encrypt) (Not the same result)

```
 String key = "aRVFPuBfEPZH6k01"; 
 DES3(key: key.codeUnits, mode: DESMode.ECB, paddingType:
 DESPaddingType.None);   
 decrypted =
     des3ECB.decrypt("9KOnBwiSR/SY60q55ashNg==".codeUnits);
```

Android output: JW3oeiEXifmR4s0x

Flutter output: %WëØpè6¢Ld7xïg´8B\M

How can I implement this code?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with "without succeed" ? Please edit your post, append the stack trace of the (?) error AND give a dataset that can get decrypted with Kotlin code (ciphertext, key and resulting plaintext, data in base64 or hex encoding), thanks.

Comment: The Android code applies Triple DES and no padding, the Dart code AES and PKCS7 padding. A prerequisite for compatibility are identical algorithms and paddings.

Comment: @MichaelFehr Thank for your comment. I mean I am not getting the same result , the post edited

Comment: Beneath the facts that DES is old, outdated, slow and maybe insecure, it could be a good idea to mention what library you are using on Dart - guessing is always a bad choice.

Comment: If the library is "dart_des" you are missing a final "print('decrypted (utf8): ${utf8.decode(decrypted)}');" to get string data encoding like on Kotlin.

Comment: @MichaelFehr this is Verifone's requirement to make a secure TCP socket communication for POS Device :\

Comment: @MichaelFehr [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Missing extension byte (at offset 4)

Comment: Decryption fails because you try to decrypt the UTF-16 code units of the Base64 encoded ciphertext. Instead, the ciphertext must be Base64 decoded, e.g. `base64.decode("9KOnBwiSR/SY60q55ashNg==")` using the _dart:convert_ library. The resulting plaintext is UTF-8 decodable, so decoding with `utf8.decode(decrypted)` is possible if required (`utf8` from the same library, see also M. Fehr's comment for the last step).

Comment: Note that Base64 encoding of the plaintext _before_ encryption is actually not necessary and only increases the amount of data (Base64 efficiency: 75%), i.e. the binary data of the plaintext can be encrypted _directly_.

Comment: @user9014097 Thanks!!! Got it.
DES3 des3ECB = DES3(key:  ENC.Encrypted.fromUtf8("aRVFPuBfEPZH6k01").bytes, mode: DESMode.ECB, paddingType: DESPaddingType.None);
  decrypted = des3ECB.decrypt(ENC.Encrypted.fromBase64("9KOnBwiSR/SY60q55ashNg==").bytes);

Answer (score 0):

If it help someone
this is the correct code

```
DES3 des3ECB = DES3(key:  ENC.Encrypted.fromUtf8("aRVFPuBfEPZH6k01").bytes, mode: DESMode.ECB, paddingType: DESPaddingType.None);
  decrypted = des3ECB.decrypt(ENC.Encrypted.fromBase64("9KOnBwiSR/SY60q55ashNg==").bytes);
```